# Consistent Styling for Nested Lists with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, nested-lists

Is there a way to make nested lists in twitter bootstrap look like a normal list, with the nested items simply indented (and have it work for an arbitrarily deep nesting)? By default, nested lists look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7o8rp0kv/1/):

[image: Nested lists with bootstrap]

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Two
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 2a</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 2b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Three
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 3a</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item 3b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make these nested lists appear like this (or in some similar way):

[image: What nested lists should look like]

In case you missed the link above, here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7o8rp0kv/1/

Answer (score 153, accepted):

**Nested Group Lists**

[image: Nested Group Lists]

```css
.just-padding {
  padding: 15px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 45px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="just-padding">

<div class="list-group list-group-root well">
  
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1</a>
  <div class="list-group">
    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.3</a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2</a>
  <div class="list-group">
    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3.3</a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3</a>
  <div class="list-group">
    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3.3</a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
  
</div>
```

View on fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/u3gd85cj/

---

**Nested Group Lists (Collapsable)**

[image: Nested Group Lists (Collapsable)]

```js
$(function() {
        
  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.glyphicon', this)
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });

});
```

```css
.just-padding {
  padding: 15px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.list-group-item .glyphicon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="just-padding">

<div class="list-group list-group-root well">
  
  <a href="#item-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1
  </a>
  <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1">
    
    <a href="#item-1-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.1
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-1">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#item-1-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.2
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-2">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#item-1-3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.3
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-3">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.3</a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <a href="#item-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 2
  </a>
  <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-2">
    
    <a href="#item-2-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 2.1
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-2-1">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#item-2-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 2.2
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-2-2">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#item-2-3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 2.3
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-2-3">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3.3</a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  
  <a href="#item-3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 3
  </a>
  <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-3">
    
    <a href="#item-3-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 3.1
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-3-1">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#item-3-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 3.2
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-3-2">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2.3</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#item-3-3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 3.3
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-3-3">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3.3</a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
  
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

View on fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/ann7tctp/

Comment: useful hierarchical list with bootstrap

Comment: Hi, could you help me get this list sortable with JQuery Sortable? I am having difficulties with the parent elements. Thanks

Comment: What is it that makes the transition smooth and gradual -- i.e. the sublists appear as if they're sliding out? I implemented this using AngularJS instead of JQuery and there is no smooth transition.

Comment: @JacobBeauchamp It's part of Bootstrap's plugins, which require jQuery to work. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: great answer, only detracting factor is that rapid clicking messes up the icon

Comment: Or `list-group-item ps-4` and `list-group list-group-flush` in subgroups.

Answer (score 9):

This was my approach:

```
    .list-group-collapse li > ul li:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }

    .list-group-collapse li > ul {
        margin-left: -16px;
        margin-right: -16px;
        margin-bottom: -11px;
    }
```

If you are using BS3, then adding the `.list-group-collapse` class to your grouped list will do the trick. See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oscar_dr/d2wpn8sd/1/

Of course, you could extend BS with this class or change the values to your custom measures if you have a customized Bootstrap.

> **EDIT:** Added snippet to answer:

```css
.list-group-collapse li>ul li:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.list-group-collapse li>ul {
  margin-left: -16px;
  margin-right: -16px;
  margin-bottom: -11px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h4>
        With collapse
      </h4>
      <hr>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-collapse">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h3>
            Level 1
          </h3>

          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <h4>
                Level 2.1
              </h4>

              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  Item 2.1.1
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  Item 2.1.2
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  Item 2.1.3
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">
              <h4>
                Level 2.2
              </h4>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h4>
        Without collapse
      </h4>
      <hr>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <h3>
            Level 1
          </h3>

          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <h4>
                Level 2.1
              </h4>

              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  Item 2.1.1
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  Item 2.1.2
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  Item 2.1.3
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item">
              <h4>
                Level 2.2
              </h4>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a really elegant approach when you consider how the code would naturally be written

Comment: The accepted answer is ok but this it's a better and more naturally solution. When u are working with a mobile sidebar that extra margins on the accepted solution would break UI  layout and second on third level wouldn't be possible for mobile devices. In think this approach with the collapsable option would be perfect.

Answer (score 9):

I modified Marcos answer to work with Bootstrap 4 (and fort-awesome icons) since glyphicons are no longer part of Bootstrap. The main changes are:

- replace glyphicons by fort-awesome icons
- add class list-group-item-action to `list-group-item`
- redefine .collapse in css (maybe there is a better approach)

```
.collapse {
    display: none;
    &.show {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ann7tctp/368/)

Comment: You may not have gotten the check for the answer or as many up votes, but definitely useful. Can you explain what `&.` is doing? Is that sass?

Comment: how can i controll the collappse event ? i want that the items are not collapsed at the start

Comment: Just add `show` class style like this: `<div class="list-group collapse show" id="item-1">`.

Comment: Great example!  Is there an easy way with JQuery I could add a button or checkbox to expand or show all of the collapsed items and if they press it again collapse all of them?

Comment: @Chris, sorry I am no experienced Javascript developer. Hopefully somebody else knows how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 7):

**Bootstrap 4 Update**

I wanted to be able to use this with bootstrap 4. Hope this helps someone else.

Here is the code using font awesome (since glyphicons are not supported in V4).

[Working jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beengie/2nLd10p7/)

Html

```html
<div class="just-padding">

  <div class="list-group list-group-root card">

    <a href="#item-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i></i>Item 1
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1">

    <a href="#item-1-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 1.1
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-1">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.3</a>
    </div>

    <a href="#item-1-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 1.2
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-2">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.2</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.2.3</a>
    </div>

    <a href="#item-1-3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 1.3
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-3">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.3.3</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <a href="#item-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 2
  </a>
  <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-2">

    <a href="#item-2-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 2.1
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-2-1">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.1.3</a>
    </div>

    <a href="#item-2-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 2.2
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-2-2">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.2.3</a>
    </div>

    <a href="#item-2-3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 2.3
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-2-3">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2.3.3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#item-3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 3
  </a>
  <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-3">

    <a href="#item-3-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 3.1
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-3-1">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.1.3</a>
    </div>

    <a href="#item-3-2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 3.2
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-3-2">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.2.3</a>
    </div>

    <a href="#item-3-3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-right mr-2"></i>Item 3.3
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-3-3">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3.3.3</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```css
.just-padding {
  padding: 15px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.list-group-item .glyphicon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Javascript

```js
$(function() {

  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.fas', this)
      .toggleClass('fa-angle-right')
      .toggleClass('fa-angle-down');
  });

});
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me using bootstrap 4.3.1. The list items have no borders and the icons do not work. Any clue why?

Answer (score 5):

**One way**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Two
                <ul class="list-group inner">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item 2a</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item 2b</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Three
                <ul class="list-group inner">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item 3a</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Item 3b</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<style>
.list-group.inner li{
 border:none;

}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7o8rp0kv/3/

Comment: This is going in the right direction, but I would like to keep the horizontal lines between list items, and the approach needs to work for an arbitrarily deep nesting. Thank you

Comment: Because the list is generated dynamically from a hierarchy of items, and I use bootstrap's collapse to make it accordion-like.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something simpler without custom CSS and Nesting. The use of Margins works well for indenting.

Make note of `ml-4` for margin below. The code indenting is actually not required as we are not creating a nested lines. Just indented for clarity.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <h6 class="text-muted">Links</h6> 
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg text-info mx-2"></i><a href="/someuser">User List</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-barcode fa-lg text-success mx-2"></i><a href="/someproduct">Products and Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-lg text-primary mx-2"></i>Reference Tables</li>
            <li class="list-group-item ml-4"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-lg text-primary mx-2"></i><a href="/testmaster">Reference Master</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item ml-4"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-lg text-primary mx-2"></i><a href="/testdetail">Reference Detail</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-lg text-primary mx-2"></i>Reference Define Fields</li>
            <li class="list-group-item ml-4"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-lg text-primary mx-2"></i><a href="/testdfmaster">Reference Define Fields Master</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item ml-4"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-lg text-primary mx-2"></i><a href="/testdfdetail">Reference Define Fields Detail</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fas fa-drafting-compass fa-lg text-warning mx-2"></i><a href="/anothermaster">Template</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The update provided by [Beengie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3802688/beengie) for Bootstrap 4 worked for me in Bootstrap 5 with a small tweak.

Need to change

```
data-toggle="collapse"
```

to

```
data-bs-toggle="collapse"
```

Comment: This is an answer to a comment, and should have been added as such