# Nested Group Lists (Collapsable) with Links

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

continuing from this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571268/4218990

what would I have to modify to create links on the items? I've tried adding a div's instead of the a-Elements, but then the links aren't working.

#### Original

```
  <div class="list-group list-group-root well">
  <a href="#item-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1
  </a>
  <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1">
    <a href="#item-1-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>Item 1.1
    </a>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-1">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.1</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.2</a>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 1.1.3</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

#### with div's and links

```
  <div class="list-group list-group-root well">
  <div href="#item-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
    <a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1">
    <div href="#item-1-1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
      <a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1.1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-1">
      <div href="#" class="list-group-item">
       <a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1.1.1</a>
      </div>
      <div href="#" class="list-group-item">
       <a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1.1.2</a>
      </div>
      <div href="#" class="list-group-item">
       <a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1.1.3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

EDIT: strangely enough it works perfectly fine on the last level in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xjcobm3y/2/

Comment: Did div's work instead of the a-elements, apart from the fact the links didn't work? If so, try setting display:block on the a-elements

Comment: thanks for your reply! 
unfortunately issue prevails with display:block and display:inline

Comment: Can you be clearer about what the issue is?

Comment: the link `<a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1</a>` and the link `<a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1.1.1</a>` are not clickable and will not get me to `www.someURL.de`

Comment: You need to then think about: what you want to have clickable to toggle the next sub-list to be expanded; and what you want to have clickable to visit the url. At the moment, you have set 'list-group-item' to toggle the next layer, and 'list-group-item' also contains the hyperlink that you want to navigate to. Perhaps make the chevron the toggler for the next sub-list, and that will then leave the hyperlink separate

Comment: you make a good point. How can I make the chevron the toggler then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps make the chevron the toggler for the next sub-list, and that
>   will then leave the hyperlink separate -Anthony

so I did just that and figured it out - see updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vwaorkpm/2/

```
<div class="just-padding">
  <div class="list-group list-group-root well">
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <i href="#item-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" data-toggle="collapse"></i>
      <a style="display:inline-block" href="www.someURL.de">Item 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1">
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <i href="#item-1-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" data-toggle="collapse"></i>
        <a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1.1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-group collapse" id="item-1-1">
        <div href="#" class="list-group-item">
          <a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1.1.1</a>
        </div>
        <div href="#" class="list-group-item">
          <a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1.1.2</a>
        </div>
        <div href="#" class="list-group-item">
          <a href="www.someURL.de">Item 1.1.3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```