# Bootstrap responsive multi columns with collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please help me how to get this done using boostrap 3. I have attached three pictures taken from desktop with different screen sizes .[responsive (desktop, ipad, iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh7Ue.png)

Comment: please show us some code you have tried

Comment: Unfortunately, I am very new to bootstrap. I have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create nested list groups and by changing their width you can create a responsive design. Using something like:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> ... </div>
```

With this way you can but 6 columns side by side in large screens and only one column for each row in smaller screens.

Bootstrap should be used with 'mobile-first design' approach. So you must design your screen according to smaller screens first and then you should consider larger screen sizes.

I advise you to spend some time in

And here is a couple of demos for nested list groups:

[consistent-styling-for-nested-lists-with-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063244/consistent-styling-for-nested-lists-with-bootstrap)

[nested list group example](http://www.bootply.com/DglnYJTSKA)

I hope this gives you a starting point.